# What does udisks-daemon do and do I need it?

Tags: hard-drive, process, services, dbus

I was looking into `htop` and the only process having > 0.0% CPU (apart from htop itself) was `/usr/lib/udisks/udisks-daemon`.

So the questions are: What is this service? Do I need it? (Or *when* do I need it?) Why is it accessing the drives?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Official package description for `udisks`:

> The udisks daemon serves as an interface to system block devices, implemented via D-Bus. It **handles operations such as querying, mounting,  unmounting, formatting, or detaching storage devices such as hard disks  or USB thumb drives.**
>
> This package also provides the udisks utility, which can be used to trigger these operations from the command line (if permitted by PolicyKit). External tools such as hdparm are used if available to implement extra operations, such as configuring disk spindown times.
>
> Creating or modifying file systems such as XFS, RAID, or LUKS encryption requires that the corresponding mkfs.* and admin tools are installed, such as dosfstools and mtools for VFAT, xfsprogs for XFS, or cryptsetup for LUKS.

---

> Do I need it?

This should be considered an essential package by almost everyone. The *only* time *I* would consider removing it is if I had a simple `/dev/sdX` CLI install on a machine where there was no need for `udev` -- i.e., **the hardware never changes** (which in practice almost always means a virtual machine, a VPS or a very very old machine).

Answer (score 0):

Here is another take on your second question about whether you need it: It depends on what your objectives are. If you want to learn about how your system works under the hood, you definitely do not need any `udisks` daemon. Not even on Ubuntu.

I am speaking out of my own experience here. The world needs more people who are curious about what is going on under the hood. See my code on GitHub for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You should also find a command line tool called `udisksctl`. With this tool you can see details what the daemon is doing in the background.

**Show Status:**

```
$ udisksctl status
MODEL                     REVISION  SERIAL               DEVICE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Micron  xxxxxxxxx         M0MA020   xxxxxxxxxxxxx        sda     
Generic STORAGE DEVICE    1454      Generic_STORAGE_DEVICE-0:0 sdb sdc 
TOSHIBA xxxxxxxxx         0100      xxxxxxxxxxxxx        sdd
```

**Monitor Progress:**

```
$ udisksctl monitor
Monitoring the udisks daemon. Press Ctrl+C to exit.
10:48:03.241: The udisks-daemon is running (name-owner :1.8).
10:48:03.404: /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/jobs/2: org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Job: Properties Changed
  ExpectedEndTime:      1699178852131486
  Rate:                 28536135
  Progress:             0.58324379569695217
```